# Filter a parent row in a QTreeView using QSortFilterProxyModel but not children

Tags: qt, qt5, qsortfilterproxymodel

How can a `QSortFilterProxyModel` be used in order to filter a row in a `QTreeView` but NOT its children nodes?

Let's say I want to filter all rows whose first column text is `Mammal` but keep the children rows (e.g. `Moose`, `Cat`, etc.)

If in the example the model contains:

```
Animals
    Mammals
        Moose
        Dog
        Cat
        Mouse
```

and when the filter is applied the view would look like this:

```
Animals
    Moose
    Dog
    Cat
    Mouse
```

Can this be done using a `QSortFilterProxyModel`? If not, I'm of course open to suggestions. But it would be nice to do it from the proxy I'm already using for other tasks.

Comment: You could reimplement `QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow` to do what you want. I'm not sure if it's the simplest solution, though.

Comment: So what would become the new parent node? Are you intending to promote the child nodes to become siblings of the parent node?

Comment: The children of a node would be displayed as direct children of its grandparent node when the parent node is filtered

Comment: @JonHarper I've just added an example.

Comment: It is not possible by filtering model. Mammal index will be hidden, so it's childs will be hidden too!
Your original model should filter itself: i.e. it should reimplement method `QAbstractItemModel::parent` and return `Animals` as parent for indexes of `Moose, Dog, Cat and Mouse`. When `Mammals` its not hidden, it should return it as parent of those four concrete mammals. Probably some other methods must be reimplemented, but this will work. Don't forget to emit corresponding signals to inform views about some of branches concealed or revealed, so they can ask your model about new structure.

Answer (score 0):

In documentation there is a method [QSortFilterProxyModel::mapToSource](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#mapToSource). IMO this is the best candidate to solve this problem. I know it is a long shot, but in conjunction with `filterAcceptsRow` it should work.

Problem is that it is not very well documented. Documentation of [base class `QAbstractProxyModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractproxymodel.html#details) says that you have to re-implement two methods: `mapFromSource` and `mapToSource`.
Qt is an Open Source project so it is best to take a look inside of `mapToSource` and its counterpart `mapFromSource`. If I will have a time I will do this and improve this answer.